# Which C++ does Visual Studio 2008 (or later) use?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I find C++ is very controversial language in microsoft world. By default we have ISO C++ and then microsoft has `Managed C++` and now `C++ CLI`.

I just know standard (ISO) C++. I don't know microsoft's version of C++.

I'm confused about interpretation of any c++ code by visual studio 2008 (or later). Thats why I'm using gnu tools for compiling my programs. But I do love Visual Studio.

What settings do I need to make if I only want to use

1. `STRICTLY` ISO C++
2. Managed C++ (its deprecated but I think they still support it for sake of backward compatibility)
3. C++ CLI (for .NET platform)

I want to build native assemblies using C++ not managed ones. So, is there anything else should I need to do?

Comment: be aware that even compiling C++ to native apps (non-managed), that the compiler still has some subtle differences to the GNU compiler. They are listed in the helpfile as 'Microsoft specific'.

Comment: This is exactly why I'm worried about using Visual Studio/Visual C++ & This is exactly why I want to know how can I ask it to `STRICTLY` follow specified thing.

Comment: No, "Microsoft specific" does not mean "Different from GCC". They mean "different from standard ISO C++". GCC does the same thing, and also has a number of extensions and unsupported features.

Comment: Microsoft have recently become much better at differentiating C++ from C++/CLI. Since VS2008, the documentation has added a new the 'Visual C++ native development' filter and online MSDN makes a distinction now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything is in the build settings:

Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) - add or remove CLR support

Advance Compile as C++ Code (/TP) - to choose if c++ or c..

Language: Disable Language Extention - use this to force ANSI.

Comment: Project properties. Right click on a C++ project and select properties.

Comment: Just to confirm: #1"MFC uses ISO C++" #2"managed C++ & C++/CLI are for .NET and  C++/CLI is replacement for managed C++". Right?

Comment: I still can't find it. I only found 

"Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" in "Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General". Rest of them I still can't find.

Comment: the c++/c is in advanced section, and the ANSI is in the Language section.
what version of VS do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

When you ask Visual Studio to make a C++ project, it makes a C++ project. C++/CLI is a different language.

VS2008 and earlier have implemented C++03 (or approximated it. Like almost every other compiler, there are bits of the standard that are not followed to the letter. A few features are not implemented (exception specifications, the `export` keyword or two-phase name lookup are the ones I can think of), and some proprietary extensions are added as well.

GCC, and most big compilers, do the exact same thing, so this isn't a case of Microsoft being "evil" as such. The extensions can be disabled, leaving you with a reasonably standards-compliant compiler.

VC2010 is adding a number of C++0x features (and at least in the beta, I haven't been able to find an option to disable these), so from a strict C++03 compliance point of view, it is going to be less compliant.

Dani's answer already tells you which settings to change to enable/disable different language dialects.